# Formatting date in Javascript, getting undefined NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

## Problem

I'm trying to format the date from something that looks like `26/05/2015 9:14:46 AM` to May 26.

I've managed to get the correct formatting on the **current day**, which is a good first step. However, in this case, I'm trying to format the date from the previous day, ie. the last time the API was updated regarding river levels `var previousDate = result[1].Date;`

I've tried `var today = new Date(result[1].Date)` console logs out `22/05/2015 9:31:19 AM` and it returns me **"undefined Nan"**

### scripts.js

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://opengov.brandon.ca/OpenDataService/default.aspx?format=jsonp&dataset=riverlevel&columns=Date&callback=?',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(result) {

      // Dates
      var currentDate = result[0].Date;
      var previousDate = result[1].Date;
      console.log(currentDate, previousDate);

      // Change date from DD/MM/YYYY to January 18
      // Create a new variable with full month names
      var monthNames = new Array ("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");

      var today = new Date();
      var dd = today.getDate();
      var mm = today.getMonth();

      // Puts everything above into a string
      var fixedDate = monthNames[mm] + ' ' + dd;
      $('.date').html(fixedDate); // This presents the fixed current date
```

Comment: The variable `fixedDate` seems to be working...it comes out to 'May 26'.

Comment: What is the value of result[1]?

Comment: @Samurai `var previousDate = result[1].Date`
Will console log out: 22/05/2015 9:31:19 AM

Comment: @AlexPan So my first step was just to get the formatting for the current day, but where I'm stuck is applying that same formatting to `var previousDate = result[1].Date`

Comment: So, for instance `previousDate = 26/05/2015 9:14:46 AM` and you'd like to print `May 26`?

Comment: `new Date("22/05/2015 9:31:19 AM")` returns `Invalid Date`. According to [Date docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) you need a date string in the specified formats.

Comment: @Jasen Since the previous date will change as the API updates, it shouldn't be hard coded. Wondering if you have a code example you could share

Comment: It doesn't matter if I hard coded it. The date string format you are using won't be accepted by the Date constructor.

Comment: @LShetty Whatever the result of `var previousDate = result[1].Date` which will typically output the date in 22/05/2015 9:31:19 AM should be changed to appear as May 22. I've only managed to do the formatting of the date correctly on the current, not previous date.

Comment: As it's not a valid Date String, I can think of a regex to achieve this!

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out the date format is not a valid one to be passed to the `Date()` function as a `dateString`, so it need to be changed to a valid one such as `yyyy-mm-dd`

```
function changeDateFormat(dt) {
    var tdt = dt.split(" ")[0].split("/");
    return tdt[2] + "-" + tdt[1] + "-" + tdt[0];
}
```

Then you can use:

```
var today = new Date(changeDateFormat(previousDate));
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/qrf73k2e/)